# How to arrange classes and interface in order to clean architecture in my data model?

Tags: java, android, architecture, clean-architecture

I've created my app's structure in next way:

`DataRepository` class has 3 members' which are interfaces. Each interface serves the appropiate datas. The first member interface works with "`Owner`" model datas, the second one works with "`Dog`" model datas. And the third must work with "`Breed`" model. First and second datas (`Owner` and `Dog`) are input from user and stored locally in SQLiteDatabase and i have classes `Dog/Owner/SQLDataSources` classes, that implement those interfaces.

The third data model is my problem. This models' list named "Breed" i download from internet, then i have to write it in database and then to get `List<Breed>`. 
As a result my `WebBreedDataSource` uploads `List<Breed>` from API and `SQLBreedDataSource` fills the database (TableBreed) with that list. So these both classes have the same method `getBreeds()`.
So i don't know which class of those does have to implements `IBreedsDataSource` interface? How to arrange this architecture clean? May be i should create some another class that uses those both and implements IBreed interface

Thanks a lot for advice!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, I would probably add another another class between your repository and your database / api controller. This class can implement your interface to get your `List<Breeds>` and it also does the "coordination" between database and api.

for example: you want to get list of breeds, okay, this "DataSourceCordinator" object does this: is the database empty?

- If it is empty, call api , fill database and retrieve the list
- otherwise retrieve what is currently in database.

You probably need something that can coordinate these two data sources somehow.

One more note, I imagine repository a bit differently than you do, I would add different data sources into single repository but for the same type of data - not mixing different types of data in one repository - only adding different ways to retrieve same type of data

for example

- for breeds you would have one repository with two data sources -
  database and api
- for dogs you would have different repository with one data source - api

Now in each repository I would coordinate these different data sources. Btw thats a nice diagram!

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your answer, i also thought in this way. But i was not sure about class-mediator name and its function in terms of clean architecture. Thanks a lot for confirming my thoughts and i hope it's a really best architecture decission.

Comment: Finally, i've reorganised my architecture. So now i have OwnersRepository, DogsRepository and BreedsRepository. My DataRepository class was deleted.